# Regular expression for email accepting some special characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I am using the following regular expression for email validation:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

The issue is that `.@xyz.com` also gets validated.

What do I need to change in the regular expression so that it checks that there is at least one `[a-z]` alphabet before `@`?

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that the email is not starting with `.` with a `(?!\.)` look-ahead, and you can make sure there is a letter before `@` with a `(?<=[a-z])` look-behind:

```
\A(?!\.)[\w+\-.]+(?<=[a-z])@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z
  ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/HQcgMZGJqg)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. `.` should not be first character. `as.@xyz.com`, `aaa.bbb@gmail.com` are valid. `.bbb@gmail.com` is invalid &

Comment: Aha, sorry I misunderstood the requirements. I think it should be working now.

Comment: +1, actually `/\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i` was my ealier regular expression but it is accepting two email id's i want only one email id. do you know how to do it?

Comment: I think the problem was in the unescaped dot that matches *any* character. So, regex should be fixed as `/\A([\w+\-]\.?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i`.

Comment: thanks a ton man, i think it should work.I'll have a look and 'll accept the answer accordingly.

Comment: Good, just in case you really need to also disallow consecutive dots, you will need to [replace `\A(?!\.)` with `\A(?!\.)(?!.*\.{2})`](http://rubular.com/r/E9EvDhbHlk).

Answer (score 1):

I won’t talk about “don’t regexp emails”. Let me guess: you probably don’t want two dots subsequently as well. For the before-at part of expression I would use `/\A(\.?\w+)+@.../`:

```
['.', '.a', 'b.', 'c', 'a..b'].map { |s| s =~ /\A(\.?[\-\w]+)+\z/ }
#⇒ => [nil, 0, nil, 0, nil]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Someone should talk about that.